# Filtering multi-lines from a log

Tags: sed, awk, grep, perl, filter

*Should this question be moved to stackoverflow instead?*

I often need to read log files generated by java applications using log4j. Usually, a logged message (let's call it a log entry) spans over multiple lines. Example:

```
INFO  10:57:01.123 [Thread-1] [Logger1] This is a multi-line
text, two lines
DEBUG 10:57:01.234 [Thread-1] [Logger2] This entry takes 3 lines
line 2
line 3
```

Note that each log entry starts at a new line and the very first word from the line is TRACE, DEBUG, INFO or ERROR and at least one space.
Here, there are 2 log entry, the first at millisecond 123, the other at millisecond 234.

I would like a fast command (using a combination of sed/grep/awk/etc) to filter log entries (grep only filters lines), eg: remove all the log entries containing text 'Logger2'.

I considered doing the following transformations:

1) join lines belonging to the same log entries with a special sequence of chars (eg: ##); this way, all the log entries will take exactly one line

```
INFO  10:57:01.123 [Thread-1] [Logger1] This is a multi-line##text, two lines
DEBUG 10:57:01.234 [Thread-1] [Logger2] This entry takes 3 lines##line 2##line 3
```

2) grep
3) split the lines back (ie: replace ## with \n)

I had troubles at step 1 - I do not have enough experience with sed.

Perhaps the 3 steps above are not required, maybe sed can do all the work.

Comment: The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one may give you some ideas.

Comment: @pmg The answear you have mentioned handles paragraphs of **fixed** number of lines.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: that's the question ... at least one **answer** handles paragraphs with unknown number of lines

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to mix many instruments. Task can be done by `sed` only

```
sed '/^INFO\|^DEBUG\|^TRACE\|^ERROR/{
         /Logger2/{
             :1
             N
             /\nINFO\|\nDEBUG\|\nTRACE\|\nERROR/!s/\n//
             $!t1
             D     }
                                    }' log.entry
```

Comment: How about both positive and negative filtering? eg: include lines containing words inc1 or inc2, but exclude entries with exc1 or with exc2

Comment: @botismarius On default all are included. If you wants to exclude two or more use form `/exc1\|exc2/` in place of `/Logger2/`. If you want to exclude everything exept inc1,inc2 use `/inc1\|inc2/!`. If you need more complex variant please show example.

Comment: I think I can manage from here. I definitely need to learn more about sed. Would you recommend any tutorial/book in particular?

Comment: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 2):

### perl filter for multiline log records (record begin mark)

Use the following perl script as a working prototype.
Usage `script_path regular_expression log_files`
e.g. `script_path "line \d" log_file_1 log_file_2`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$pattern = qr/(?^s)$ARGV[0]/; shift; # process filtering expression
# (?^s) - treats matched string as single line
my $line = ''; # accumulates current log file record/paragraph
while(<>) {
 if( /^(TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|ERROR) /o ) { # start of new record
   &flush; # flush/print previous recors
 }
 $line.=$_;
}
&flush;
exit;

sub flush {
  local $_ = $line;
  if( length($_) and /$pattern/ ) {
    print;
  }
  $line = '';
}
```

Comment: This is useful. However, I preferred the answer `sed` as it had good chances of being faster.

Answer (score 2):

Based on one answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one this seems to fit the bill

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

PATTERN1='TRACE *';
PATTERN2='DEBUG *';
PATTERN3='INFO *';
PATTERN4='ERROR *';
LINEOUT=""
while read line; do
    case $line in
        $PATTERN1)
                echo $LINEOUT
                LINEOUT="$line"
                        ;;
        $PATTERN2)
                echo $LINEOUT
                LINEOUT="$line"
                        ;;
        $PATTERN3)
                echo $LINEOUT
                LINEOUT="$line"
                        ;;
        $PATTERN4)
                echo $LINEOUT
                LINEOUT="$line"
                        ;;
        "")
                LINEOUT=""
                ;;

        *)      LINEOUT="$LINEOUT ## $line"
                ;;
    esac        
done
echo $LINEOUT
```

*NB: This will add a blank space at the begining of output*